# Omitting the UIColor.setFill() error message?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I have two functions side by side that are looped to constantly draw two UIBezierPaths, the thing is, each of them have a different color so I constantly need to reiterate `UIColor.blackColor().setFill()` and `UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "normalpaper.jpg")).setFill()`, the downside is it makes the console impossible to read because it's endlessly spamming the warning message you get.

```
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error.
This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby
contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This
notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an
upcoming update.
```

And thus, here is my question, is there a way of doing this that would not spam my console with this warning message? Perhaps a way of making it so the warning message would not appear? (Couldn't find one with searching) Or maybe a way of omitting the message? Any input is very appreciated, thanks for reading -Zach.

-

If you need the draw `functions`, there they are below

```
func drawCircle() {

    //Setting the draw color
    UIColor.blackColor().setFill()

    // Creating the rectangle's size
    var drawRect = roundDrawRect(10.0, angle: 7)

    //Incrementing the coords
    ++y
    ++x

    //Drawing the rectangle
    drawRect.fill()

}

func eraseCircle() {

    //Setting the eraser color
    UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "normalpaper.jpg")).setFill()

    //Decrementing the coords
    eraseX = x - 2
    eraseY = y - 2

    // Creating the rectangle's size
    var eraseRect = roundEraseRect(10.0, angle: 7)

    //Drawing the rectangle
    eraseRect.fill()

}
```

Full CircleView class below
(I'm still very new to programming, so it's probably quite inefficient)

```
//Creating a view capable of painting the circle
class CircleView: UIView {

//Starting X Pos
var x: CGFloat = 100
var eraseX: CGFloat = 100

//Starting Y Pos
var y: CGFloat = 100
var eraseY: CGFloat = 100

//Starting the loop of functions
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    //Creating the looping draw timer
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
        0.2,
        target: self,
        selector: Selector("timerDraw"),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)

    //Creating the looping erase timer
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
        0.3,
        target: self,
        selector: Selector("timerErase"),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)

}

func drawCircle() {

    //Setting the draw color
    UIColor.blackColor().setFill()

    // Creating the rectangle's size
    var drawRect = roundDrawRect(10.0, angle: 7)

    //Incrementing the coords
    ++y
    ++x

    //Drawing the rectangle
    drawRect.fill()

}

func eraseCircle() {

    //Setting the eraser color
    UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "normalpaper.jpg")).setFill()

    //Decrementing the coords
    eraseX = x - 2
    eraseY = y - 2

    // Creating the rectangle's size
    var eraseRect = roundEraseRect(10.0, angle: 7)

    //Drawing the rectangle
    eraseRect.fill()

}

func timerDraw(){

    //DO DRAW LOOP HERE
    drawCircle()

}

func timerErase(){

    //DO ERASE LOOP HERE
    eraseCircle()

}

//Defining the rounded rect erasing (Circle)
func roundEraseRect(radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

    //Creating the rounded rect (Circle)
    var roundedRect = UIBezierPath()

    roundedRect.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(eraseX,eraseY))
    println(CGPointMake(eraseX,eraseY))

    roundedRect.addArcWithCenter(CGPointZero, radius: radius,
        startAngle: 0, endAngle: angle ,
        clockwise: true)

    return roundedRect
}

//Defining the rounded rect drawing (Circle)
func roundDrawRect(radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

    //Creating the rounded rect (Circle)
    var roundedRect = UIBezierPath()

    roundedRect.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(x,y))

    roundedRect.addArcWithCenter(CGPointZero, radius: radius,
        startAngle: 0, endAngle: angle ,
        clockwise: true)

    return roundedRect
}




}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

Comment: Where are you calling `drawCircle()` and or `eraseCircle()`? The context is important here because you can only call drawing code at very specific times places.

Comment: @MikeS Hey again, Mike. I'm calling them in a custom Class added right above ViewController (Not inside), it's a custom class called CircleView (I added it as a subview inside of viewDidLoad), It's subclass is a UIView so it can properly paint the images, the issue is the console being spammed by error messages. I'll add the whole class for you to check to make sure if you so desire.

Comment: Well, the problem is with those timers you have in `drawRect`. Can you explain what you are trying to do with those?

Comment: @MikeS What I'm trying to do is make it so a circle on the screen is constantly moving `+1x +1y` every 0.2 seconds. Every 0.2 seconds the timer calls the `drawCircle()` function that draws the circle with a different position slightly. Same as the `eraseCircle()` function draws a background-colored circle over the old circle position after a slight delay to give it the illusion of it being erased. Or at least, that's the goal, it hasn't actually painted the images on the screen yet.. Still working out the kinks..

Comment: @MikeS Oh yeah, the drawRect() method is just the only method I could think of I could override, so it would always be called right away, there's a better way of doing this, I imagine?

Comment: @MikeS Now that I think about it.. I heard something about "Threading" that could accomplish something similar.. Time to do some research, but in the meantime, is there something wrong with using NSTimers?

Comment: At the very least, you should use [`setNeedsDisplay`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW136) from your timer, and then move all your drawing code to happen from inside of `drawRect`. But please just read the documentation first. You don't need threads for this.

Comment: As @KurtRevis just said, "Threading" is not the solution for this. Not only will it not solve your problem, but it will make it worse and add quite a bit of complexity while doing it. You should definitely read [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Apple's [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156) explains all of this, I *highly* recommend reading it before going further with custom drawing code. At an absolute minimum, read the section on [iOS Drawing Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW1).**

---

The problem is that you're creating and firing `NSTimer`s inside your `CircleView`s `drawRect` function. Drawing calls can only be made in the right context (which is actually what the error you're seeing it trying to tell you). By doing the drawing in functions invoked from your `NSTimer`, you're actually doing the drawing **outside** your `drawRect` function and there isn't a valid drawing context in that case. Also, with the code the way it is, you'll be starting new timers each time the system needs to redraw your view; that could get out of hand very quickly as the timers start overlapping.

However, with just a bit of rearranging, we can make this work.

***Please Note:** This isn't necessarily the right way to go about what you're doing with your circle animation, but it will solve the particular problem that you're asking about with with regards to the invalid context error.*

1. Take everything out of `drawRect` and replace it with calls to `eraseCircle` and `drawCircle`.
2. Take the logic that you have to increment `x` and `y`, and `eraseX` and `eraseY` out of `drawCircle` and `eraseCircle` and put that in `timerDraw` and `timerErase` instead.
3. Instead of calling your drawing code directly in `timerDraw` and `timerErase`, tell the view system that you need your view redrawn by calling [`setNeedsDisplay()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCADHC). That will flag your view as needing to be redrawn and the view system will call your `drawRect` function again automatically as soon as it can.
4. Make your timers work again by overriding `didMoveToSuperview` and start them there; you should also add logic to stop them if they're already running.

***Steps 1 and 3 are the critical bits that makes your error go away.***

Something like this:

```
//Creating a view capable of painting the circle
class CircleView: UIView {
    // Timers
    var drawTimer: NSTimer?
    var eraseTimer: NSTimer?

    //Starting X Pos
    var x: CGFloat = 100
    var eraseX: CGFloat = 100

    //Starting Y Pos
    var y: CGFloat = 100
    var eraseY: CGFloat = 100

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        eraseCircle()
        drawCircle()
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        // If we have active timers, stop them
        if var drawTimer = self.drawTimer {
            // This stops the timer
            drawTimer.invalidate()
            self.drawTimer = nil
        }

        if var eraseTimer = self.eraseTimer {
            // This stops the timer
            eraseTimer.invalidate()
            self.eraseTimer = nil
        }

        // If we're actually part of the view hierarchy, start the timers
        if self.superview != nil {
            //Creating the looping draw timer
            self.drawTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
                0.2,
                target: self,
                selector: Selector("timerDraw"),
                userInfo: nil,
                repeats: true)

            //Creating the looping erase timer
            self.eraseTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
                0.3,
                target: self,
                selector: Selector("timerErase"),
                userInfo: nil,
                repeats: true)
        }
    }

    func drawCircle() {
        //Setting the draw color
        UIColor.blackColor().setFill()

        // Creating the rectangle's size
        var drawRect = roundDrawRect(10.0, angle: 7)

        //Drawing the rectangle
        drawRect.fill()

    }

    func eraseCircle() {
        //Setting the eraser color
        UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "normalpaper.jpg")).setFill()

        // Creating the rectangle's size
        var eraseRect = roundEraseRect(10.0, angle: 7)

        //Drawing the rectangle
        eraseRect.fill()

    }

    func timerDraw(){
        //Incrementing the coords
        ++y
        ++x

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func timerErase(){
        //Decrementing the coords
        eraseX = x - 2
        eraseY = y - 2

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    //Defining the rounded rect erasing (Circle)
    func roundEraseRect(radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

        //Creating the rounded rect (Circle)
        var roundedRect = UIBezierPath()

        roundedRect.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(eraseX,eraseY))
        println(CGPointMake(eraseX,eraseY))

        roundedRect.addArcWithCenter(CGPointZero, radius: radius,
            startAngle: 0, endAngle: angle ,
            clockwise: true)

        return roundedRect
    }

    //Defining the rounded rect drawing (Circle)
    func roundDrawRect(radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

        //Creating the rounded rect (Circle)
        var roundedRect = UIBezierPath()

        roundedRect.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(x,y))

        roundedRect.addArcWithCenter(CGPointZero, radius: radius,
            startAngle: 0, endAngle: angle ,
            clockwise: true)

        return roundedRect
    }
}
```

As to the best way to achieve the animation you're attempting, you could look at just drawing the circle once and then, in your `UIViewController` moving the entire view on a timer. Or, possibly better, using [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Or, if your final product is going to be a game (or even game like), maybe take a look at [Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I will read that now, and as for moving the entire background, that won't work because the goal I'm trying to accomplish is somewhat of a puzzle game, the circle moves at a predetermined pace, and you click the screen to change it's surroundings, I don't know how well that would translate to sprite kit either, guess I will have a look there. Thanks.